# Julia: How to select entire row from array

Tags: arrays, row, julia

Ok, so I am still getting stumped by basic syntax.  Right now I would like to know how to create a matrix filled with a single value c and once created how to replace an entire row.  So far this is what I have:

```
c = 5
nrow = 6
ncol = 4
parm = [c for i=1:nrow, j=1:ncol]
parm[5, 1:end] = 0

parm
6x4 Array{Any,2}:
 5  5  5  5
 5  5  5  5
 5  5  5  5
 5  5  5  5
 0  0  0  0
 5  5  5  5
```

The above syntax works but seems unnecessarily verbose.  Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Francis

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `fill` function to construct an array filled with a specific value:

```
julia> A = fill(5,(6,4))
6x4 Array{Int64,2}:
 5  5  5  5
 5  5  5  5
 5  5  5  5
 5  5  5  5
 5  5  5  5
 5  5  5  5

julia> A[5,:] = 0
0

julia> A
6x4 Array{Int64,2}:
 5  5  5  5
 5  5  5  5
 5  5  5  5
 5  5  5  5
 0  0  0  0
 5  5  5  5
```

You also don't need to write `1:end` – you can just write `:` for that.